# Circular argument requirement for wrapper

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, maya

I'm attempting to attach a listener to a window object that is destroyed when the window is closed.

However, the window object does not have an `OnClose` type method that is called from clicking the X to close (It's Autodesk Maya's `pymel.core.uitypes.Window` if you're curious why).

`add_listener` creates a listener that exists in the active session. `attach_listener` I am creating to cause the listener to remove itself when the window closes, and requires a window to be attached to.

My solution is as follows:

```
def attach_listener(window, event_name, function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if window.exists():
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            remove_listener(id_number)
    id_number = add_listener(event_name, wrapper)
```

This obviously won't work because `id_number` is not defined until after the function is declared, however, I cannot pass the function to `add_listener` without defining it first. `id_number` cannot be passed to `add_listener`. What do I do to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this kind of approach:

```
def attach_listener(window, event_name, function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if window.exists():
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            remove_listener(wrapper.id_number)
    wrapper.id_number = add_listener(event_name, wrapper)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shucks :\
You can hack it in the following way; I think this will work....

```
def attach_listener(window, event_name, function):
    IDlist = []
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if window.exists():
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            remove_listener(IDlist[0])
    IDlist.append(add_listener(event_name, wrapper))
```

Not the most elegant way to do this, but it should work.... 
If it doesn't let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately, Maya runs in Python 2.6, so `nonlocal` doesn't exist.